# Does WebStorm supports PGP?

Tags: git, github, webstorm

I am trying to use PGP with the current version of WebStorm for remote Git. However, each attempts fails?

I get the following error on attempting commit-push

```
0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: [+] Initial commit after reinstallation of 'angular 2 seed advanced' and refactoring to com-epimss.ng2.ts [!] INCOMPATIBLE WITH version: 0.0.0 gpg: cannot open tty `no tty': No such file or directory error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Is it possible to use WebStorm with PGP?

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm calls git w/o [terminal (tty)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132) and your GPG key needs password.

You need trigger an agent and add a passphrase for your GPG key.

If you are on **Windows**, this should helps:
https://jamesmckay.net/2016/02/signing-git-commits-with-gpg-on-windows/

If you are on **Unix**, I cannot help you, sorry.

---

Or, [you can remove GPG passphrase](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-gpg-change-passphrase-command/). **But it is very dangerous security risk!** Use it only if you want to test it with a key created for this purposes.